# How to apply scaled translation to line chart in plotly (js)

Tags: plotly

I would like to display several line curves with a perspective effect, in order to be able to compare them more easily:

[image: Scaled translations]

I have been able to produce the above example by applying an offset to the data itself just before rendering, which is of course not ideal, as it breaks things like the data on hover, and will require more maintenance.

It must be noted that I've tried the 3d approach, with a proper camera setup. Although it works fine for one plot, in real life I want to be able to align several subplots (the above example is made of 2 subplots), and I have a feeling that automatically computing the proper cameras to align each 3d subplot is quite a hard problem.

The code I am porting to js was using python matplotlib's [ScaledTranslation](http://matplotlib.org/api/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation), but maybe plotly uses a different term ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [there's no built-in support for this](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-apply-scaled-translation-to-line-chart/3694) ATM.